# Why is SYSTEM_DRV Partition suddenly being listed in File Explorer Windows 10 Lenovo?

Tags: windows, windows-10, partitioning, windows-explorer

I never saw this partition in my file explorer and I guess only in Disk Partition. But, suddenly I see it now in explorer. What happened? Someone hacked my PC and doing crazy things?? :O

And is it safe to be listed openly in file explorer?

However, I am not able to open it. It's saying access denied though I am the administrator.

[image: Screenshot]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing it because a driveletter was assigned to it.

From DiskManagement, rightclick the partition, and choose Change drive letter and path, and remove the drive letter.

This drive is only containing the bootloader, and does not need to have a driveletter assigned to it.

Comment: Actually, there is no drive letter assigned. See the another snapshot. And also no option are given when I right click on the drive in disk management, except help. Anyhow, I will try to reboot and check. But, the mystery is why it is suddenly listed by itself???

Comment: Could be that something assigned a driveletter temporarily and explorer hasn't understood it no longer has a letter. A reboot should fix it. As to why, thats only a matter of guessing.

Comment: Is it better if I don't reboot now? What if someone hacked my system and put something in this partition to happen on boot? :O

Comment: Why did something plays with boot partitions? Yes, it could be really nothing or it could be really something big. I have been watching Mr. Robot series these days and that's why I'm little paranoid. :P

Comment: Or it could be my Lenovo Solution Center doing something in background. Hmm..Will see.

Comment: Just reboot. You'll be fine.

Answer (score -1):

simply go to the settings and then navigate to advanced startup.
In that select startup repair..finished. I had same problem just yesterday :)